# AWS network ACL: why do I need to allow outbound port 80 to be able to browse Internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, acl

I am very new to AWS and networking. I have been playing with network ACL. I realized that if I don't allow outbound port 443 (HTTPS) on the network ACL, I wouldn't be able to use a browser to go to https://www.google.com **from within the EC2 instance** in the subnet associated with this ACL.

Likewise, if I don't allow outbound port 80, I wouldn't be able to go to http://www.cnn.com.

This confused me. When I allow port 80 outbound on the ACL, am I allowing the EC2 to talk **to port 80** on the CNN server, from an ephemeral port on my EC2, or am I allowing the EC2 to initiate a connection **from port 80** on the EC2?

Comment: You should not have outbound port rules at all. They add nothing in terms of security. Off topic.

Comment: But this is what I am talking about: if I don't allow outbound port 80, I won't be able to browse Internet from within that EC2. But, obviously, next question is: do I need to browse Internet from within my web server? I thought I need, to download patches etc. Am I right?

Comment: But that is what *I* am talking about. You shouldn't have an outbound rule. That means you shoudn't *disallow* it. You shouldn't have rules about outbound ports at all. Allow them all.

Comment: For all the nice people around this forum: my question is not a thee-page long one, It is quite short. If you do not bother to read my question, please don't bother to just cut and paste a chunk of AWS documentation. I don't need that. You are wasting your time and mine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the security groups at instance level to have security at instance level.And unlike security group, ACL is stateless and works at subnet level i.e if you want your instances to communicate  over port 80(http) then you have add an inbound and outbound rule allowing port 80.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But again, you are simply restating the AWS documentation without even bother to read my specific question.  I don't need someone to read the AWS documentation to me. I can read it myself. I hope someone would bother to read my specific question and answer it.

Comment: Okay, I got it when you are allowing outbound rule on port 80, you are allowing to connect to other web servers on port 80 and listening on ephemeral ports.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I was allowing to connect to **their** port 80, when my port could be any ephemeral port, right?

Comment: Also, when my Chrome browser talks to CNN's port 80, what ephemeral port does it use on my machine? Any port, or port 80 as well?

Comment: You can check it by using command sudo netstat -tupn . there you will see list of connections made by your browser. 
P.s I am answering this from mobile app so please ignore any typos.

Comment: Done it. All clear. Thank you again for spending the time to help! New question: what is the security benefit of limiting what ports on **other** servers **my** machine can talk to?

Comment: @SillyDude , Have you got to know what port to specify on other servers? Meanwhile i am in your stage of understanding things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add any rules. The default network ACL is configured to allow all traffic to flow in and out of the subnets to which it is associated. Each network ACL also includes a rule whose rule number is an asterisk. This rule ensures that if a packet doesn't match any of the other numbered rules, it's denied. You can't modify or remove this rule.

Rules allow all IPv6 traffic to flow in and out of your **subnet**. We also add rules whose rule numbers are an asterisk (Catch All) that ensures that a packet is denied if it doesn't match any of the other defined numbered rules.

A network ACL has separate inbound and outbound rules (Stateless), and each rule can either allow or deny traffic.

Out Bound Rules allow outbound traffic from the **subnet** to the Internet. In other words it is **matching the traffic flow** with the **defined rules** in the ACLs list and apply it (ALLOW/DENY).

If you have private instances that should not be accessible by public users in the internet it is best practice from security point of view to place these instances in a **private subnet** and use NAT instance in a **public subnet** and make all traffic flow goes through this NAT instance to make patch updates and get the public access.

For more information, Check [Amazon Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html)

Comment: Thanks but you did not address my question. You basically just copy and paste the standard documentation here.

Comment: I copied the parts that are relevant to your question. please read it again and let me know what is missing to clarify more

Comment: did you chck this "If you have private instances that should not be accessible by public users in the internet it is best practice from security point of view to place these instances in a private subnet and use NAT instance in a public subnet and make all traffic flow goes through this NAT instance to make patch updates and get the public access."

Comment: The EC2 was on a public subnet. It is meant to be used as a web server.